# Getting Instagram cookies from Js chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get my Instagram cookies with my js chrome extension and `document.cookie` is missing a lot of needed cookies that i can see using cookie editor extensions.
here are the permissions i set.

```
"permissions": ["activeTab","scripting" , "cookies","tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://soundcloud.com/*","*://*.findsocial.io/*","*://*.instagram.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
```

`console.log(document.cookie)`
Onyl showing few cookies

Comment: are the "missing" ones `httpOnly` cookies perhaps?

Comment: Hmm, didn't think of that, the cookie editor I'm using doesn't show any info other than name and value, anyway to get those ?

Comment: what is a cookie editor? anyway, browser *developer* tools is where you'll find cookies